# Show that unhomogeneous linear differential equation degree $n$ has $n+1$ roots independent linearity on $(a,b)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that non-homogeneous linear differential equation degree $n$ has $n+1$ roots independent linearity on $(a,b)$ with coefficients in equation are continuos funtions on $(a,b)$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? Regards

Comment: What is a root of a non-homogeneous linear ODE?

Comment: Why $n+1$ root? what is that +1?

Comment: this is a problems in my book . I can't slove it . Can I help me an idea for this problems . thank you so much. My english is not good.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that a homogeneous linear differential equation of order $n$ has $n$ linearly independent solutions?

Do you know that the general solution of a non-homogeneous linear differential equation takes the form, particular solution plus general solution of corresponding homogeneous equation?

Given that, can you see how to get $n+1$ linearly independent solutions?

It's like this: if $A$ is a matrix and $Ax=0$ has $n$ linearly independent solutions then for nonzero $b$, $Ax=b$ has $n+1$ linearly independent solutions (if it has any solutions at all). If you understand that fact from linear algebra, you should see how it applies to differential equations.

Comment: I known the non-homogenerate linearity order $n$ has $n$ roots.But in this problem talk $n+1$solutions. I thinks it's not true.

Comment: Please look at $$\pmatrix{1&2\cr2&4\cr}\pmatrix{a\cr b\cr}=\pmatrix{0\cr0\cr}\tag1$$ and $$\pmatrix{1&2\cr2&4\cr}\pmatrix{a\cr b\cr}=\pmatrix{3\cr6\cr}\tag2$$ and notice that the solutions of (1) form a one-dimensional family but (2) has the two linearly independent solutions $(1,1)$ and $(3,0)$. Do you understand that?